# Django Foreign Key duplicate column

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a prexisting MySQL database that contains a table with a foreign key to another the table. I used `inspectdb` in Django 1.10 to form the following models from it :

```
class Contested(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey('Candidate',default=None)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    num_votes = models.IntegerField()
    per_votes = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    incumbent = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False 
        db_table = 'contested'
        unique_together =(("district","state","year","candidate","num_votes"),)

class Candidate(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'candidate'
```

However when I attempt to migrate I get `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'candidate_id'")`
 I believe this is because I already have a foreign key relation in my db ( column candidate_id is already in the Contested table), yet Django is attempting to construct the relation itself by adding column `candidate_id` to the Contested table (although managed is False).

Is there a way to for Django to recognize the Foreign key relation already exists?

Comment: Have you tried to use `migrate --fake-initial`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#adding-migrations-to-apps

Comment: Ok so when I try to follow the documentation you posted: `makemigrations "app_name"` then `migrate --fake-initial`, the first one detects my models, but the second `migrate --fake-initial`, doesn't detect any changes. And the Class meta of the models, including `unique_together` isn't detected (i.e I am getting an error for Contested that there is no contested.id) .

Comment: It seems only when I remove `managed=False` does django recognize `unique_together`, but then the migrations show that it then attempts to create the `Contested` table, which exists.